# Django api update/create request from test case never fired the related methods in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How i can send the UPDATE or CREATE request from my test case? When i run my test case the create/update methods never fired in serializer..
What i misunderstand in Django philosophy?
Can someone suggest what i have to do?

For example:

```
#View
class  filesPairView (viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = filesPairViewSerializer
    
    def create(self, request):
    ...
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


#Serializer
class filesPairViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        ...
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print ("filesPairViewSerializer CREATE")
        

    def update(self, validated_data):
        print ("filesPairViewSerializer UPDATE")
        


#Test case
class filesPairViewTestCase(APITestCase):

    def test_barmi(self):
        print("test_barmi")
        url = ('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/filesPairView/')
        data ={
        #some valid data
        }

        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


#urls
router.register(r'filesPairView', views.filesPairView )
```

Comment: I could only use one "tricky way": I add a message type record to request data. The request fires filesPairView.create method and here i can handle anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

```
#Test case
from django.urls import reverse

class filesPairViewTestCase(APITestCase):

    def test_barmi(self):
        print("test_barmi")
        url = reverse('filespairview-list')
        data ={
            #some valid data
        }
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


#urls
router.register(r'filesPairView', views.filesPairView, basename='filespairview')
```

Notice that the trick here is use the `basename` which is normally in singular and has the following result based on REST:

- `reverse('filespairview-list')` -> `/filesPairView/` - `GET` - List all
- `reverse('filespairview-list')` -> `/filesPairView/` - `POST` - Create
- `reverse('filespairview-detail')` -> `/filesPairView/{int:pk}/` - `GET` - Get one
- `reverse('filespairview-detail')` -> `/filesPairView/{int:pk}/` - `POST` - Update one
- `reverse('filespairview-detail')` -> `/filesPairView/{int:pk}/` - `PATCH` - Update partial